# Get the next row defined by an offset in oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a function which takes an integer parameter. I need to return the row which is the next, second,
previous from the current row. E.g. 1 means the next row, -1 the previous row, 2 the
second row from the current etc.

In other words the function must first store a value into a variable, which represents the next, previous or same row. This is to be defined by an offset parameter which the function expects. The code below only adds or subtracts the offset value to current row value.

The function also uses a global variable from the package interface, in order to pinpoint the row which needs to be offset-ed.

```
    function my_function (v_offset integer) 
    return number 
    is

    var flight.flightID%TYPE;

    BEGIN
    if v_offset>0 then
     select something
     INTO var
     from somewhere
     where id = v_global + v_offset; 
    else 
     select something
     INTO var
     from somewhere
     where id = v_global-givennr; 
     end if;
    RETURN var;

  end my_function;
  /
```

This is my code so far.

Comment: Yes only one parameter.

Comment: it is defined in a global variable because is within a package.

Comment: I just uploaded it...

Comment: And what is the problem with the code you've posted?

Comment: I want to display the next row not the row which is offseted. For example if the parameter will be one. It will be added to the id . But the table is unordered.

Comment: So - you are onto something with your last comment. When you say next row, or previous row, what do you mean? Rows in a table are not ordered in any particular way; if you WANT ordering, for example, by id, you must make that explicit in your "select something ..." query. (Probably not by adding the offset directly to id though, unles id's are consecutive integers - very rarely the case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LAG and LEAD analitic function. LAG(column_name,offset) over(order by xxx) .
I assumed that your table is ordered by column id.

LAG - return value from previous rows.
LEAD - return value from next rows.

```
create table somewhere(id number, something varchar2(20));

-- populate table with data.
    insert into somewhere
select level, chr(64+ level) from dual 
connect by level < 25;

 declare 
   v_global number :=10; 
   p_offset number :=-5;
   v_resutl varchar2(20);
 begin

  select val into v_resutl from (
  select id, case when  p_offset >0 then lead(something,abs(p_offset)) over(order by id) 
                  when  p_offset<0 then lag(something,abs(p_offset)) over(order by id) 
                  when  p_offset =0 then something  end val
  from somewhere) where id = v_global;

 dbms_output.put_line(v_resutl);
 end;
```